# Using asynchio while iterating over a list for api params

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous

My goal is to make asynchronous API requests while passing in elements from a list as params. The params value 'asin' is what needs to be passed in from the list `asins` for each iteration.

The code works correctly when list `asins` is a single element. When I use 3 elements I get an api error which reads as if all 3 elements are being passed in at once.

What am I doing wrong?

```
import requests
import asyncio
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

asins = ['B09J2BVQR4', 'B08YYPYGSL', 'B085M66QYC']

params = {
'api_key': api_key,
'type': 'product',
'amazon_domain': 'amazon.com',
'asin': asins
}

def request(session, asin):
    url = 'https://api.rainforestapi.com/request'
    with session.get(url, params=params) as response:
        data = response.json()
        if response.status_code == 200:
            print(data['product']['title'])
        else:
            print(response.text)
        return data
        
async def start_async_process():
    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        with requests.Session() as session:
            loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
            tasks = [
                loop.run_in_executor(
                    executor, request, *(session, asin)
                )for asin in asins
            ]
            for response in await asyncio.gather(*tasks):
                print('test')

future = asyncio.ensure_future(start_async_process())
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(future)
```

Comment: Use of the asyncio library here is unnecessary.  Your concurrency is provided by the ThreadPoolExecutor, not asyncio. If other parts of your code are using asyncio, then you may wish to use the aiohttp library.

Comment: Regarding the 3 element list, yes, that is exactly correct. You set params exactly once, with the three element list. You then send that params 3 times in as part of three separate requests. To send just one element per request, you need to copy `params` in each `request()` and then set `asins` to a single element list. eg. `new_params = dict(params, asins=[asin])`